# typo3 condition [globalVar = TSFE:id = 3] applies to all pages

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I have typo3 8.7.16 .

I need to display on the page with id 3 the content in a format different from the rest of the pages. For this I use glovalvar, but this condition works on all pages, not only on the page with id 3

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 3]
    MAIN_WRAP >
    MAIN_WRAP = COA
    MAIN_WRAP{
      10 = CONTENT
      10{
        table = tt_content
        select.where = colPos = 0
      }


    }
    [global]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you make a mistake in your expectations, I see the following optional faults:

- The code you have above the condition but which is not shown here could seem to produce the same result as the code inside the condition. I write here intentionally `seem` as it's quite possible that the produced html is different but on the website it's currently looking the same.
- The code in the condition might not be triggered at all as the object path might be wrong. Perhaps it must be like this or something similar:

  page.10.subparts.MAIN_WRAP >
  page.10.subparts.MAIN_WRAP = COA
  page.10.subparts.MAIN_WRAP {
      ...
  }

There still might be other reasons but if you have checked the mentioned reasons you should edit your question to show the context of your code in the question.

Comment: thanks, it really helped me. It was reason of my mistake

Comment: Typoscript conditions always needs to be on top level, you can't use conditions inside shortcut braces (`{`, `}`). Inspect your typoscript with the Template Analyzer to see such syntax errors.

Answer (score -1):

your TS looks not so bad. instead of [global] try [end]

http://www.thefox.ch/extdev/typo3/typoscript/conditions/

Comment: there is no difference and it won't be a reason for any problem.
I use `[global]` too without undesired effects.